# Creating single variable to consolidate multiple classes

Tags: python

I have a dictionary (dict1)

```
dict1={
    'lala':{
            'name':'lala',
            'lula':0xcafecafe,
            },
    'mene':{
            'name':'mene',
            'lula':0xdeadbeef,
            },}
```

After that i created a register class to parse in the information

```
class register:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = dict1[name].get('name')
        self.data = dict1[name].get('lula')

    def self_add(self):
        value = self.data + self.data
        print('self_add value : {}'.format(value))
```

and create a for loop to populate the it

```
for name, info in dict1.items():
    reg_class = register(name)
    vars()[reg_class.name]=reg_class ##work
    vars()['base_path'+'.'+reg_class.name]= reg_class ## not working
```

however, when i use `vars()[reg_class.name]=reg_class` it is working

```
>>> mene.data
3735928559
>>> hex(mene.data)
'0xdeadbeef'
```

but when i use `vars()['base_path'+'.'+reg_class.name]= reg_class` it is not working

```
>>> base_path.mene.data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'base_path' is not defined
```

How can i do that correctly?

Comment: The correct thing to do is to create a `dict` of `register` objects, rather than injecting new names in to the local scope.

Comment: The reason i add this was because i would like to have some function coming with the class instead for example a sellf_add function so when we call mene.self_add it will return a value
>>> mene.data
3735928559
>>> mene.self_add()
self_add value : 7471857118
>>>

Comment: @Enzo what is lula?

Comment: It's because of the dot after base_path, please modify it to 

vars()['base_path'+'*'+reg_class.name]= reg_class

Use any other delimiter instead of "*" but not "." because when "." is used, it considers it to be a different variable and tries to find a path inside it ( which is not there as bas_path is not defined)